# How can I get Google Hangouts chat to work via Tor browser?

Tags: firefox, proxy, gmail, privacy, tor

My friend's company is blocking Gmail access. I directed her to the [Tor browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) bundle. She was able to login to her Gmail account successfully (via https://www.gmail.com/ URL). However, the Google Hangouts widget disappears after a couple of seconds.

I was able to reproduce the issue here in the U.S. with the Tor browser. Tried the following without success:

- Proxy turned off (Tor button -> Preferences -> Transparent Torification option)
- Turned off all options in the "Security Settings" tab (Tor button -> Preferences)
- Removed "NoScript" and "HTTPS-Everywhere" extensions

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get Google Hangouts to work via the Tor browser?

Comment: hi, FYI: though Tor is safe, the stream is visible in a network capture (the contents, destination etc. aren't decipherable though). If she has signed any sort of agreement or, a company policy warning is always shown when starting the PC/browser etc., Tor usage could be dangerous. Also, hypothetically, the company could capture the undecipherable stream and later potentially use it for any data loss issue etc. though she was just chatting.

Comment: Beaming, this issue has been ticketed. Thanks for raising it as well.
https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/11214